# How to get a mapping of ids to their respective cluster?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cluster-analysis

I did a clustering analysis using DBSCAN with random data for now. However, at the end I would like to the a mapping like this:

```
[Cluster, Total_users]
[A,10]
[B,6]
[C,60]
```

The starting point is this code I have but at the end, the output is missing this list. Does somebody know what I should do?

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

data = np.array([[-37.530, 3.109, -16.452],
                    [40.247, 5.483, -15.209],
                    [-31.920, 12.584, -12.916],
                    [-32.760, 14.072, -13.749],
                    [-37.100, 1.953, -15.720],
                    [-32.143, 12.990, -13.488],
                    [-41.077, 4.651, -15.651], 
                    [-34.219, 13.611, -13.090],
                    [-33.117, 15.875, -13.738]])


model = DBSCAN(eps=2.5, min_samples=2)
model.fit_predict(data)
pred = model.fit_predict(data)

print("number of cluster found: {}".format(len(set(model.labels_))))
```

Comment: `pd.Series(pred).value_counts()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
print(Counter(model.labels_))
```

The out put will be like

```
Counter({1: 5, 0: 2, -1: 2})
```

where,

label 0 has 2 elements
label 1 has 5 elements

and -1 with two means outliers in dbscan.

Alternatively,
You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(pred).value_counts()


 1    5
-1    2
 0    2
dtype: int64
```

as suggested by  @Quang Hoang which gives the same output.

Comment: Aunsid and Quang Hoang thank you both for the help! it works!